Organization departments or sub-types for employer hierarchies?
I'm wondering if there's any way (or if there might be any interest in a future feature) to create a nested level of an organization to represent things like university departments, city agencies, etc.
Real world case scenarios:
Sometimes I want to find all of my contacts who work for the City of Philadelphia.
Sometimes I only want to find those who work for the City's Water Department, or Parks & Rec department.
Ideally, if I labeled someone as working for the Water Department, Civi would know that they also work for the City.
Same thing when I'm dealing with the local university, where there might be three levels of hierarchy:
University > School of Design > City planning program.
Ideally, a contact who's affiliated with the city planning program would show up in searches for that employer, but also in searches for the School of Design or specific University. And a higher-level search for the University would reveal that contact as well as contacts in other programs / departments.
I could maybe do that with child-tags although that might get messy, and I'd love to see this kind of hierarchy within Civi's employer field.
Does this exist? If not, would it be helpful to others?
Thanks!
-jj
PS I'm using Civi to organize Walk Around Philadelphia, a ~100+ mile exploration of the city's wild boundaries that happens twice a year as a public event (or anytime you want to set out to walk the border yourself) – if you're in the area you'd be most welcome to join.

I think it would be useful - there is already the concept of what I call daisy-chaining relationships via the Permissioned Relationship extension - so that if i have permission to see A (the Uni) and the Uni has permission to see B (the Dept) and the Dept has permission to see C (their Staff). Then A will be able to see C.

I suspect that building a SK block to display this on eg Contact Summary screen is probably also possible

But I think your idea of searching - which makes a lot of sense - would need to be a new feature - and perhaps it could be tied in with the extension i mentioned (or borrow stuff from it) - https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions
